# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < into DOCTYPE html PUBLIC

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a series of JavaScript problems and the only thing I notice in the console.log is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Which leads me to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I can not see a syntax error here. Is there any syntax error in this line? How can I fix it?

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you trying to load html as a javascript-script file?

Comment: Need more information. Is it inline javascript? Are you including a script tag with a `src` leading to a page with a doctype?

Comment: What is the JavaScript that is throwing this error?

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: That's old doctype, so unless you are required to use that doctype I'd advise using HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: It is the proxy page when i try to access google recaptcha. i Trying to see why GOogle Recaptcha v1 does not appear when i do change the radio button, to see two diferent forms

Comment: Can you post the JS code from your page that is making a request to google.com or whatever? It sounds from your last comment that there's code on your page either making an AJAX call or inserting a `<script>` tag which requests from the recaptcha service, and this is likely returning an error (I would guess 404, maybe 401, maybe 50x) with an html body instead of JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message indicates a JavaScript syntax error.

The code you quoted is XHTML, which is not JavaScript. Trying to treat it as JavaScript (as you are doing) is doomed to failure.

This is probably caused by entering the wrong URL in a `src` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

With HTML 5 simply use  ***`<!DOCTYPE html>`***

and `<script type="text/javascript" src="YourFileName.js"></script>` in the `<head`> section.

And don't forget to replace your java file name(.js).